# ipython apt-get installation/removal issues

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, apt-get

When I try to use ipython I can't... but when I install it or list with apt-get, it says it's already there.  However when I try to remove it, I also can't.  I'm stuck!  How can I use apt-get to have ipython in a usable state?
(Working on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ ipython
The program 'ipython' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ipython

selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ sudo apt-get install ipython
[sudo] password for selah: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ipython is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.

selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ apt --installed list | grep ipython
ipython/trusty,now 1.2.1-2 all [installed]
ipython-qtconsole/trusty,now 1.2.1-2 all [installed]

selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ sudo apt-get remove ipython
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ipython ipython-qtconsole
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,688 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'doc-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'smartgithg': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ipython
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/588 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package ipython.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'doc-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'smartgithg': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: perhaps better to `pip install ipython` and see if you get the same result.

Comment: @ShawnMehan, this comment does not tackle the problem.

Comment: probably related: http://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to force reinstall ipython?

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ipython
```

Comment: I tried that and got similar errors, pasted the output in the original question.  Thanks for the idea thought.